# Nested Sortable plugin consistently crashes browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scZtb/1/

Be warned, as the title suggests, this might crash your browser (or at least the tab, if you're in Chrome).

I'm trying to get [this example](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) to work. I've copied it almost exactly, so I don't know why it would work there, but not in my example.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to only work with `<ol>`s not `<ul>`s. I can't imagine why that is, but I can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Not sure why you are wanting/needing .nestedSortable, which I don't see documented on the jQueryUI site.  When I change it to use .sortable, it appears to work correctly. (Using latest Firefox)</del>

Okay, you are using the selector 'ul' in this case, your example doesn't have a nested UL element, but when you do, you are effectively calling the plugin on the original outer list, and again on the inner list...

See recursion...  When you use a generic selector with jQuery/jQueryUI you select **ALL** matching elements, and are calling the plugin on the outer item, then the inner item...

Comment: I'm using nestedSortable because I need nesting. As stated in the title, it's a plugin. And if you click the "this example" link or look under "resources" on the fiddle, you'd see which plugin I was talking about.

Comment: Your updated answer isn't correct either. `.nestedSortable` isn't "live" -- it doesn't apply to future elements. You can test this by giving the 'outer' list an ID, and applying `.nestedSortable` to only that; same problem occurs.